# log4j StringToMatch in property file

Tags: properties, smtp, log4j

I have following XML configration i would like to convert to java property file.

I am getting below error

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [filter] to value "org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter".
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [true].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: true
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:326)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppenderFilters(PropertyConfigurator.java:881)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:812)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:395)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
    at simpandfile.main(simpandfile.java:10)
```

My XML configration

```
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
    <param name="StringToMatch" value="FileNotfound" />
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
  </filter>

  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR"/>
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
    </filter>

  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
```

After converting the property file is as below. With XML configration it is working fine.

Property File

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, MAIL

log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
# here's where I specify the layout and the pattern

log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=xxx.example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=xxx@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.To=xxx@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Test Email.
log4j.appender.MAIL.threshold=error
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%n%n%-5p%n%n%c%n%n%m%n%n
log4j.appender.MAIL.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.MAIL.filter.StringToMatch=Filenotfound
log4j.appender.MAIL.filter.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.MAIL.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter


log4j.logger.com.devdaily.myapp=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Please let me know how i can use StringToMatch in property file and specify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Properties files don't support filters. You'll have to switch to an XML configuration.

From the documentation of Filter :

> Note that filtering is only supported by the [`DOMConfigurator`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html). The [`PropertyConfigurator`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) does not support filters.

---

**Resources :**

- [log4j - Filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [Why chose XML over properties files for Log4J configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256835/why-chose-xml-over-properties-files-for-log4j-configuration)

Comment: The syntax for adding Filters to an appender is: log4j.appender.appenderName.filter.ID=fully.qualified.name.of.filter.class log4j.appender.appenderName.filter.ID.option1=value1 ... log4j.appender.appenderName.filter.ID.optionN=valueN I see this in above link you have sent. I am not really very sure about this

Comment: Answer is correct... I tested 1.2.15, 1.2.16, 1.2.17 and PropertyConfigurator did not work for filters... I read your below comment ("It works. 1.2.16 – Jan Zyka Nov 15 '11 at 8:48") ... But this is not true @JanZyka . Could you please share your configuration???

Comment: Works fine for me using properties files with 1.2.16 and 1.2.17. Does not work for 1.2.15 or 1.2.8.

Comment: Filters _do_ work for me as well when setup from `log4j.properties`.

Comment: In an "ideal world", everybody would be using log4j2 instead of log4j (whose "official" end of life was in 2015).
Nevertheless, Propertyconfigurator *DOES* support filters for log4j-1.2.16 and 1.2.17 (the final log4j release).

Answer (score 34):

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.console.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.console.filter.1.StringToMatch=entered
log4j.appender.console.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.console.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

does work

Comment: I've tried this and it DOES WORK.   Check the Log4j version.  I was using 1.2.16.

Comment: This is documented in the [PropertyConfigurator Javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html)

Comment: It works on preformatted text, before applying conversion pattern.

Comment: The javadoc is not quite upto date as it does not reflect the source code (or perhaps the other way around) I have a hard time of figuring out where to look for the most uptodate. I wrote a full answer on multiple filters here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085162/multiple-filters-for-log4j-using-properties-file/59090027#59090027 depending on your version of log4j the way to enable multiple filters changes