# Filtering Exceptions On Log4J 1.X

Tags: java, filter, log4j

Firstly must say, i cannot change my log4j.properties to log4j.xml or i cannot change my log4j version 1.x to 2.x due to some reasons. I need to ignore three exceptions for fileAppender i did two exceptions with stringfilter but it does not work third one. My Exception and property file is:

```
07 Apr 2017 | 11:45:26,499 | ERROR | SFSWorker:Ext:1 | Extensions |     | EXCEPTION
com.smartfoxserver.v2.exceptions.SFSJoinRoomException: Join Error - Room is full: 19, Zone: { Zone: Batak } - Can't add User: ( User Name: d354e22339937548abb52ec442eb4eb4, Id: 3, Priv: 0, Sess: 88.253.243.151:33453 )  
at com.smartfoxserver.v2.api.SFSApi.joinRoom(SFSApi.java:990)
```

My Property is:

```
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.1.stringToMatch=FORCE_UPDATE
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.1.acceptOnMatch=false
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.2.stringToMatch=REGULAR_UPDATE
log4j.appender.fileAppender.filter.2.acceptOnMatch=false log4j.appender.consoleAppender.filter.3=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.filter.3.stringToMatch=Room%20is%20full
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.filter.3.acceptOnMatch=false
```

I do not want to see exceptions that contains "Room is full" on my fileAppender. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your configuration of log4j I think it will be difficult.

You can see answers of question [log4j StringToMatch in property file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730343/1811730)

> Properties files don't support filters. You'll have to switch to an XML configuration.

But check the Log4j version sometimes it works :

See comment for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3960938/1811730

[EDIT]

Sorry, I did not read the question correctly :-(

Maybe the problem is `%20`
Have you tried without: `log4j.appender.consoleAppender.filter.3.stringToMatch=Room is full`

Comment: For FORCE_UPDATE and REGULAR_UPDATE. It works but when i try to filter Room is full it doesnt work.