# Does log4cplus support xml configuration file and conditional logging?

Tags: c++, log4j, log4cplus

I want to use MDC to set a context in my program, and then be able to set a filter in the config file to only show messages from a logger in a certain context.

```
MDC mdc; 
mdc.put("fieldName", "foo"); 
LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(log, "ABC"); 

mdc.put("fieldName", "bar"); 
LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(log, "XYZ");
```

I only want to print from `log` when `"fieldName"` is `"bar"`, so only "XYZ" should be printed to my log.

In log4j this [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404435/conditional-logging-with-log4j) using the XML format config file with filters. Can log4cplus use an XML config file? Can filters like this be set up in the XML log?

Also, is there a way to make log4cplus verbose, so I can see if it is finding my config file, and if it is able to read it, etc.

I am having trouble finding even one example of a log4cplus XML config file or how to read one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4cplus does not support any kind of XML configuration file. This is because it would require an XML parser and that is a pretty heavy dependency.

As for the filtering using MDC, there is currently no such filter. You would have to implement your own. See the [`Filter`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1spi_1_1Filter.html) class.

You can set up log4cplus debugging from property file using `log4cplus.configDebug=1`. Or you can set the `LOG4CPLUS_LOGLOG_DEBUGENABLED` environment variable to `1`. The former takes precedence over the latter.