# Is there any new features in log4j 2.0 or logback that can seperate logger level into thread basis?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, logback, log4j2

My class has a logger, and the class is used by many threads. Besides using thread-local technology, is there a native feature in log4j 2.0 or logback or even other logging technology that can change the logger level for a special thread and leave the logger level for other threads unchanged?

Comment: That's an interesting requirement. Could you explain why you need it?

Comment: actually, the class is gonna be a servlet serving client requests, so there may be a special user connected to my server and I want to change log level for that special user

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7404435/3080094