# How to programmatically setup slf4j logger with SLF4JBridgeHandler

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm trying to setup slf4j to intercept all logging statements and then programmatically add the handlers based on certain conditions. My code is:

```
private void init()
{
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

    if(condition1)
        appendHandler(console, Level.DEBUG);
    if(condition2)
        appendHandler(logfile1, Level.INFO);
    ...
}
```

How do I write the code for `appendHandler` method? I've just spent a few hours trying to read through documentation and cannot find a solution. There are lots of references on how to do it in configuration files but not in code.

Also am I correct in that this code intercepts all logging statements for all the different logging frameworks?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404435/conditional-logging-with-log4j)

Comment: Basically the `SLF4JBridgeHandler` is only routing all the JUL log records to the SLF4J API. So first of all the code will not intercept all the different logging frameworks but only the `java.util.logging`. Also Calling `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();` adds a handler for you, so what kind of handling do you need ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Also am I correct in that this code intercepts all logging statements for all the different logging frameworks?

SLF4JBridgeHandler is a `java.util.logging` (JUL) logging bridge, which will "intercept" the JUL logging statements and route them to the SLF4J.

Other bridges available are `jcl-over-slf4j` (Jakarta Commons Logging => SL4J) and `log4j-over-slf4j` (Log4J => SL4J) (as well as their SLF4J => X counterparts).

Depending on which logging frameworks are used in your code (either directly or indirectly), you may want to include some or all of these,
to capture *all the logging statements*, as detailed [here](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

[image: SL4J legacy bridges]

> How do I write the code for appendHandler method?

#### Using SLF4J (e.g. Logback) as your primary logging framework

Once you have setup your bridges, you can then configure your SLF4J implementation in a usual way.

Below is an example of how to do this for [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/):

```
//Install the JUL Bridge
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

//Obtain an instance of LoggerContext
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

//Create a new FileAppender
FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> file = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
file.setName("FileLogger");
file.setFile("error.log");
file.setContext(context);
file.setAppend(true);

//Filter out anything < WARN
ThresholdFilter warningFilter = new ThresholdFilter();
warningFilter.setLevel("WARN");
warningFilter.setContext(context);
warningFilter.start();
file.addFilter(warningFilter);

//Message Encoder
PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
ple.setContext(context);
ple.setPattern("%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} %msg%n");
ple.start();
file.setEncoder(ple);

file.start();

//Get ROOT logger, and add appender to it
Logger root = context.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
root.addAppender(file);
```

#### Using JUL as the primary logging framework

If what you want is to use *JUL* (java.util.logging) as your primary logging framework,
you do not need to register the *SLF4JBridgeHandler* at all.

Just configure *JUL* handlers as usual, and add the `slf4j-jdk14` (i.e. SLF4J => JUL) bridge to your list of dependencies.

```
//Create a new Handler
Handler fh = new FileHandler("error.log");
fh.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

//Register it with the ROOT logger
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);

//Log some messages
Logger.getLogger("scratchpad").info("Info !");
Logger.getLogger("scratchpad").warning("Warning !");
Logger.getLogger("scratchpad").severe("Severe !");

//Log some messages via SL4J 
LoggerFactory.getLogger("scratchpad").error("sl4j message");
```

This way any *SL4J* log statements will be redirected to the appropriate *JUL* handlers (you may also want to add `jcl-over-slf4j` and `log4j-over-sl4j` in the mix too).

Comment: The last two lines do not work for me. The Logger interface does not provide these two methods.

root.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
root.addAppender(file);

Comment: @RichardBurkhardt Make sure that you have imported the "ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger" (a Logback implementation class) and not the SL4J Logger ("org.sl4j.Logger") (or just use a FQN class name).