# How can I use Marker in log4j.properties to filter some log?

Tags: java, logging

I use this in my program, but how can I filter this log in log4j.properties.

```
Marker marker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("tp-count");
log.info(marker, "The num of tp is {}", 10);
```

The log4j.properties is like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,F
log4j.appender.F=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.F.File=client.log
log4j.appender.F.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.F.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.F.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using log4j 2.0, You can filter your logs using `MarkerFilter` as described in [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter)

Also please note, that you need to switch from `properties` configuration to `xml` configuration in order to **enable support of Filters** as clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730423/8513835). You just can not implement filtering using `properties` approach!

You can use this [online tool](https://log4j-props2xml.appspot.com/) to quickly convert properties to xml. Consult with  [this section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) of manual to make sure your log4j2.xml is placed and named correctly so that it will be picked up by your application automatically

Your final log4j2.xml can look like as in following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="F" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

        <!-- below forces inclusion of only log events with marker 'tp-count' to this client.log-->
        <MarkerFilter marker="tp-count" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

        <param name="File" value="client.log"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] %p %m (%c)%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="F"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: log4j2.properties does have support of Filters! E.g. see the example in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397001/5718513

Answer (score 2):

The question is about using [Marker](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter) in combination with configuration via propertie file. I will answer for log4j2 version 2.11. with an example.

Sample project files:

**log4j2.properties**

```
status = error


appender.ana_whitespace.type = RollingFile
appender.ana_whitespace.name = ana_whitespace
appender.ana_whitespace.fileName = ${sys:es.logs.base_path:-target}${sys:file.separator}ana_whitespace.log
appender.ana_whitespace.filter.1.type = MarkerFilter
appender.ana_whitespace.filter.1.onMismatch=DENY
appender.ana_whitespace.filter.1.onMatch=ACCEPT
appender.ana_whitespace.filter.1.marker=ANA_WHITESPACE
appender.ana_whitespace.policies.type = Policies
appender.ana_whitespace.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.ana_whitespace.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.ana_whitespace.policies.time.modulate = true

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.ana_whitespace.ref = ana_whitespace
```

**Example Java code**

```
package de.es.stemmer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.MarkerManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectMessage;

public class JsonLoggerTest {
    final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(JsonLoggerTest.class);
    final static Marker MARKER_WHITESPACE = MarkerManager.getMarker("ANA_WHITESPACE");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        System.setProperty("es.logs.base_path", "target");
        LoggerContext.getContext().reconfigure();
        log.info(MARKER_WHITESPACE, "msg_sourceSnippet whitespace");
    }

}
```